# How to remove KDE desktop from Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde

So I installed kde desktop from this repository

```
 ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

and installed it

```
sudo apt-get install kde-standard kubuntu-desktop
```

I don't like KDE and want to get ride of it.
Is there a way to completely remove KDE desktop with its software without braking my Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved by using [`ppa-purge`](http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/) to remove the packages you installed from the KDE Backports PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

Comment: sadly it removed some software but not all, I guess there is no way to do this task

Comment: Perhaps you need a `sudo apt-get autoremove` (or `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`) after that.

Comment: sadly I am getting errors like this 
Depends: plasma-scriptengine-javascript (= 4:4.10.5-0ubuntu0.1) but 4:4.11.1-0ubuntu2~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed

Comment: Perhaps `sudo apt-get -f install` will do the trick?

Comment: I think yes at least it is  removing stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

I used Synaptic Package Manager to remove it. It worked very very well.

The only thing that I would recommend is to have caution, since it is a very powerful program. Also, be patient and detail oriented.

look for the KDE Desktop Environment section and mark all installed packages for complete removal. Double check your choices and proceed once satisfied.

It will take a few minutes to do the job, but it will. It was easy and it even restored the Ubuntu greeter instead of the Kubuntu greeter.

Hope this works!

Comment: This also worked well for me! Using Synaptic to choose which packages belong to KDE is clearly safer than using apt-get, although it involves a **lot** of clicking. I'm back to the good old Ubuntu now.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-full
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

This will do the trick

edit: the first command will delete kde-full package, the second command will delete all remaining kde packages depending on kde-full which no longer exists

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: this helped me..

Comment: It helped you, sure, but please explain.